# Is there a "setSharedElementsUseOverlay()" method for Fragment transitions?

Tags: android, android-animation, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

During a shared element Activity transition, shared elements are drawn in the window decor view's `ViewOverlay` by default. If necessary, the developer can disable this default behavior by calling the [`Window#setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSharedElementsUseOverlay(boolean)) method. The [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) class, however,  does not seem to declare a similar method for Fragment transitions.

For Fragment transitions, are shared elements also drawn in a view overlay on top of the fragment's view hierarchy by default? If so, is there a way to disable the default behavior as there is in the Activity transitions API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, shared elements in Fragment Transitions are not drawn in the overlay by default. However, ChangeTransform *can* pull a shared element into the overlay when it detects that its transform and its parent transform differ. You can disable this in the ChangeTransform transition by setting

```
android:reparentWithOverlay="false"
```